# Import list variable from separate files in python

Tags: python

**script.py**

```
list = ['one',
        'two',
        'three']
# python script here
```

My list is getting really long (about 400 lines)... Is there a way to have the variable `list` in a separate py file and import it?

Or should I have separate file and create a list by iterating over it?

**list.txt**

```
one
two
three
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Save it in a .json file and load it with `l = json.load(file.json)`

Comment: I would recommend choosing a variable name other than the built-in `list`, though.

Comment: You can `pickle` your list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! Simply create another python list and import it in the main program.

in variables.py

```
mylist = ['this', 'that', 'theother']
```

in main.py

```
from variables import mylist
```

Answer (score 4):

Sure why not?

vars.py

```
mylist = [
'one',
'two',
'three',
'four',
]
```

main.py

```
from vars import mylist
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `pickle` here:

```
try: 
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

my_list = ['one',
        'two',
        'three']

pickle.dump(my_list, open('my_list.pkl', 'wb')) 

my_list = pickle.load(open('my_list.pkl', 'rb'))
```

Comment: I'd only do that in a `try`/`except` block. `try: import cPickle as pickle except ImportError: import pickle. Reason being: cPickle isn't available on all computers and in Python 3, cPickle is imported in place of pickle if it's available. However, good choice in pickle, it's one of the best ways of storing data.

Comment: @Zizouz212, thanks I didn't know that was an issue, I never ran into a problem with that. I will update my answer to reflect your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Shashank and Justin provided great answers but if you really wanted to keep it as a text file you might want to try this:

`myfile = open('listFile.txt', 'r')
for word in myfile:
    list.append(word)`

Comment: `myfile` is simply a file object. To get the file contents, you should use `for word in myfile.read()`.

Comment: I've just recently learned this and it's great. Sorry for formatting (on mobile) but in python it becomes as easy as "words = word.split() for word in open(" file.txt", "r") if len(word.split()) == 4". This simple, easy to read, one liner puts all the 4 letter words in your file into the array 'words'. So brilliant.

Comment: With an if clause thrown in too

Comment: That's a list comprehension

Comment: Then yes. List comprehension