# Trying to import python list into another document?

Tags: python

hello i am very new to stack overflow community so i hope you can understand i am new to python as well. at my school we are doing python we have not been taught it much and we have been assigned a task of making a log in for authenticated users as well as some other code that we are going to be looking into more detail in class.
we were told to try at home to make the authenticated users log in. the requirements have to be that it has to get the data from a table from another file and that if its not that user then it will ask it to try again. This is what i tried to do. We learnt how to do the loops i think that this is right.

this is my main.py

```
from variables import authUsers
import time


##Import All Variables

count = 0

while count != 3:
    authenticate = input('Please enter a Valid Username')
    if authenticate in open(variables.py, 'r').readlines(1):
        print ("hello")
else:
    exit
```

and this is the variables.py i made

```
authUsers = ['userA', 'userB', 'userC']
```

it returns an error saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\Computer Science\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    if authenticate in open(variables.py, 'r').readlines(1):
NameError: name 'variables' is not defined
```

i cant exactly understand why its not able to identify it they are in the same directories. thx again.

Here are the websites i looked at to try and get an answer to my problem but i couldnt figure out what was rong.

[Import list variable from separate files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267006/import-list-variable-from-separate-files-in-python)

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/try-every-username-and-password-from-a-list-on-a-website

Comment: `open()` expects a string literal but you are passing `variables.py`. You already imported, properly, from that file. You don't need to open python modules, just import them. `if authenticate in authUsers`

Comment: Since you are importing `variables.py` as a module, you don't need to read it in as a file. Try replacing `if authenticate in open(variables.py, 'r').readlines(1):` with `if authenticate in authUsers:`

Comment: okay thank you very much @roganjosh and prithajnath i thought you would have had to add it again to make it work! haha

Comment: No problem. As for your question under the answer, 99.99% of the time you won't want to `open()` your python module. I've not done it in 4 years but I can imagine some fringe cases where you might want to. This is what the `import` system is specifically designed for.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. I thought at first import was only for things like that time function so yeah that makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already imported the `variables.py` file at the top of your main file. You don't have to open it and read lines from manually later, because it is already executed and the data is in memory already.

```
from variables import authUsers # this already imports the variables.py module.
...
if authenticate in authUsers: # you can just use the authUsers 
    ...                       # no need to readline again
```

Comment: oh right thats cool. thank u very much. is it better to import it that way?? or should i change my code and remove the topline of variables and change it to `if authenticate in open(variables.py, 'r').readlines(1):` if i have other of variables?? sorry we dont get taught python in school much since its out of our gcse now

Comment: @Foxy `open()` function is for reading any  file contents. Since what you have is not a generic file, but specifically a **python** file, `import` is better because it will **execute the code** in the file and make the variables available.  If you have multiple objects, you can use `import variables` and then access each variable with the dot attribute access notation, as in `variables.authUsers`, `variables.another_variable`, `variables.some_function()` etc. Everything in the module is available.